# How To Open an Existing Android Studio project in Android Studio without launching last opened proect

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to open existing Android Studio Project without launching Android Studio with last closed project.

i.e When I launch Android Studio then it opens last closed project on it.
Then I have to close it or go to 
File menu -> Open -> Open File Or Project

Rather than i wants to open it from windows file explorer/finder or from terminal where project is stored.
like Xcode, Unity and other IDE does.

Or we can say.

can we create a special Android Studio Launcher icon for separate Project in that project directory.

Comment: macOS users can use automator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731813/how-to-run-an-android-studio-project-directly-from-the-finder/54904356#54904356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can launch android's specific project in android studio from command line tool `studio`.

Go to directory where project is stored

```
user@:~/AndroidStudioProjects$ studio MyProject
```

If the commands don't work you can run in Studio > `"Tools" -> "Create Command Line Launcher..."`

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible. Other IDE projects create a "project file" that associates the contents of the project to that specific IDE.

Netbeans for example is not one of those, and so is Android Studio.

There are only [two ways to open a project for Android Studio.](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-to-open-a-project-in-Android-Studio)

Hopefully in the future they will implement a simpler way to do it!

Comment: is there any way when we launch Android Studio every time we get <b>Open From the Studio project dialog</b> i.e first one from link you provided

Comment: Nope, that is an integrated function of the IDE, and not an external action. That wouldn't be possible. As I said, hopefully they being in ease of use later on but for now we cannot. Android Studio projects (like netbeans) are seen as the 'Entire' project folder, not just a single file like in VS for example.