# How to run an Android Studio project directly from the Finder?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, finder

How to open an Android Studio project from the Finder? I see the below list of files. Is it possible to double-click one of them to get it opened by Android Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no **one-click run** solution like I expect you have with some IDEs like Visual Studio or CodeBlocks.

All you need to do is open your Android Studio and then import a project.

---

EDIT: I've already run Android project in Android Studio using `Terminal` (using Ubuntu 14.04LTS). This is my full command:

```
 ./android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh workspace/Android/glucosio-android/
```

Hope you find it useful

Comment: Thanks, this is - at least - a possibility.

Comment: yes, thanks to this you can create bash scripts, but it's still not the same  with click one file and open whole project

Answer (score 6):

You can create command line launcher `Tools > Creat Command-line Launcher`

If you are using macOS then create an Automator Quick action.

1. Configure like following
2. Add a run shell script, then paste `/usr/local/bin/studio $@`. Make sure pass input is changed to as Arguments.
   [image]
3. Save it (say Open with Android studio), then right click on the studio project folder > Quick actions > Open with Android studio. Or if you don't have much quick action this will list in the bottom of the context menu itself.
   [image]

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in all cases. For example when the AS is installed on external drive the command launches it without settings and it fails to find SDK... I discovered launching AS this way works better: `open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app $@`

Answer (score 2):

No, You need import the project from the Android studio.

There isn't a way to open directly from finder. What you need to do is:

On Android Studio go to File Menu -> New... -> Import Project

Answer (score 1):

- In Finder, select the ListView_Ex2.iml file.
- Right click, and select Get Info
- Under Open with: select Other and choose Android Studio, then Always Open With, and click Add.
- Click Change All...

You can now double-click any IML file to open that project.